# Is the statement below an iff statement?

Tags: linear-algebra

7.14 of LADR 3rd edition:

For a complex vector space,$V$ And $T \in L(V)$. If $<Tv,v>=0$ for all $v \in V$, then $T=0$.

Kind of a dumber question but was going through the textbook, when i came across this, seems pretty clear to me that this should be an iff statement, is there any reason why we would use an if-then statement for this instead? Is there an exception where $T=0$ but somehow $<Tv,v>$ isnt $0$ Or is the other direction obvious enough such that there is no point in writing it as an iff statement.

Comment: It is **iff**, but the reverse direction is fairly clear.

Comment: Thanks for the help